# Search for multiple words, mark words without match

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming a query "house garden garage" in the search term. The documents in the index only contain "house, garden", "garden, garage" and "house garage" but no document contains all three words together.

Currently the query is build with a split_keyword analyzer and an operator "AND". So the query wouldn`t return any results.

But if one search word is omitted there are results.

Is it possible to return documents only matching a subset of the 3 terms and get the omitted terms in the result ?

At the moment the only way I see for this is to execute the query with "OR" as operator and explain enabled and pick up the scores for the single words for each field and find the not matching term. But this seems extremely unintended.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Named Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) would be very helpful here. You could write your query in should clause with `_name` param to figure out which words matched for e.g

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "your_field": {
              "query": "house",
              "_name" : "house"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "your_field": {
              "query": "garden",
              "_name" : "garden"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "your_field": {
              "query": "garage",
              "_name" : "garage"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In results check for `matched_queries` field which will tell you which words it matched and then you will be able to figure out which terms were omitted